# Picker Inside Menu Doesn't Update First Time

Tags: swiftui, menu, picker

I've put a `picker` inside a `menu` so I can apply custom text and images in the future.  It seems that, on a new app launch, the `menu` only gets updated on a second tap though.  On the first tap the `picker` check-mark gets an update, however neither the `ViewModel` nor the `menu` change until a second tap.  Any ideas on how to have all the components work every time?

```
class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var soundSelection: String = "Off"
    @Published var soundSelectionPickerValue: Int = 0
    
    func updateSoundSelection(to: Int) {
        var updatedSoundSelection: String
        switch to {
        case 0:
            updatedSoundSelection = "off"
        case 1:
            updatedSoundSelection = "chime"
        case 2:
            updatedSoundSelection = "alert"
        case 3:
            updatedSoundSelection = "peaceful"
        default:
            return
        }
        soundSelection = updatedSoundSelection
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var viewModel: ViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Menu {
                Picker("", selection: $viewModel.soundSelectionPickerValue) {
                    Text("off").tag(0)
                    Text("chime").tag(1)
                    Text("alert").tag(2)
                    Text("peaceful").tag(3)
                }
                .onChange(of: viewModel.soundSelectionPickerValue) { tag in
                    viewModel.updateSoundSelection(to: tag) }
            } label: {
                VStack {
                    Text(viewModel.soundSelection)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that your call to .onChange() is inside of the Menu. This call could go any number of places since it depends on the variable, in your case 'viewModel.soundSelectionPickerValue' changing, not on the Picker itself. Move this modifier outside of the Menu and it will work just fine.